# Sourcetree blank page

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, atlassian-sourcetree

i've succesfully installed Sourcetree and logged in into my GitLab but nothing shows up when selecting a repo from the list. All the repos are shown correctly.

Anyone has a solution?

Thank you

[balnk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3xFw.png)

I tried to log out and log in again with no luck.

Comment: Unless you have a large number of repos to clone, maybe you can manually clone then with `git clone` and then add them to sourcetree?